# RDS falls over after server creation in CFBuilder

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, coldfusionbuilder

I am using CFBuilder 2.0.0 and I can connect to RDS fine so my CF instance is definitely set up correctly. However, as soon as I create a server using the following technique:-

- Right click on project name > ColdFusionServer Settings
- In servers drop down select 'Add Server...'
- In new dialogue choose 'Import configurations from RDS server' selecting me RDS configuration
- I leave all the settings the same on the first page apart from selecting Is Local and changing the Host Name as my CFadmin and my website are on different hosts
- In local server settings I choose the JRun4 install folder for Server Home and the the root of the project in Eclipse as the Document Root
- I do not install the extensions
- Click finish

Now when I try and expand the RDS connection I get an alert box saying:-

*Could not initialize class com.adobe.rds.core.services.messages*

I am totally stuck here and would appreciate any help.

Comment: Shouldn't it be the /jrun4/servers folder?

Comment: @MarkAKruger do you mean the Server Home? If you do I am pretty sure that is wrong as if I choose any other folder than c:\Apps\JRun4 (in my case) then CFBuilder says 'Server home is not valid.'

Comment: Right... but I seem to remember on cfbuilder you had to point to the instance you wanted. Wouldn't that be /jrun4/servers/*instancename* ? I could be wrong. I don't use Multi-server for my local install.

Comment: @MarkAKruger well in my install the cfinstances are setup as follows. c:\Apps\JRunservers\myinstance inside this folder is cfusion.ear\cfusion.war etc. If I point the server root at c:\Apps\JRunservers\myinstance I get 'Server home is not valid.' So still no love I am afraid :(

Comment: I must be wrong... sorry - I got nothin :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that you cannot configure CFBuilder to work if your CF Admin and your application do not reside on the same host name. Quite why this is is anyone's guess.

To resolve this I needed to make the server I configured on my project use the same host as my CF Administrator. This is obviously very counter intuitive, and means that if CFbuilder launches the browser for you for debugging it will get the wrong domain name. However, if you start the debugging session and then manually browse to the page in the browser then the debugging does work.